# Devices on the switch can not be detected by the router with a specific gateway

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have 3 hosts (computers).
The 3 hosts used to connect the router directly and the IP address of them are `192.168.0.101,192.168.0.102,192.168.0.103`

Recently, I bought a switch and I linked all 3 hosts to the switch. Then, I linked switch and the LAN port of the router.

The question is if the gateway was the set to `192.168.0.1` in the router, the 3 hosts can not be detected by the router. But after the gateway changed to `192.168.50.1`, the 3 hosts can be detected.

I want to keep the original IP address of my 3 hosts. How can I do to solve it? Why does not the `192.168.0.1` detect the 3 hosts?

Appreciate for any help.

### update

below is the screenshot of the router config.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of "setting a gateway" in the router?

Comment: @user1686 sure, please check, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your gateway to 192.168.254.1, and still keep the same address on your hosts.
As for the reason... I suspect it may be related with some auto-config feature on the switch. If it is possible, try to disable it.